# testing neural networks in r- with confusion matrix

Tags: r

I have used this code to create a neural network

```
set.seed(9850)
group<-runif(nrow(bc))
bc<-bc[order(group), ]
bc_train<-bc[1:178, ]
bc_test<-bc[179:198, ]
library(nnet)
nn_bc<-nnet(V2~., data=bc_train, size=10)
pred_bc<-predict(nn_bc, bc_test, type="class")
table(pred_bc, bc_test$V2)
```

The code runs without giving any errors however when I test the model with the last line giving me out a table where it gives a confusion matrix it seems to ignore the fact that there is two categorial variables and produces this:

```
pred_bc  N  R
  N 13  7
```

I can't see what is wrong with my code as I have used it on other data sets.

Answer (score 0):

The neural network has predicted only one class as the output. 
Try printing

```
    factor(pred_bc)
```

to see if there are any other levels other than N.

Comment: Its saying there is only one level, have I coded it wrong? There is definitely two levels

Comment: The test set has only 20 rows which all could have been predicted as N. Try with some more data. May be bc_test<-bc[159:198, ] will work just to check your predict function.

Comment: I checked the data it definitely had both N and R. I have used this code on the iris data set and it works perfectly. I don't understand why it wont work here.

Comment: would it just be predicting the more dominant category?

Comment: Another possible reason could be when there are too many class 'N' in training dataset compared to class 'R'. This is known as class imbalance problem. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis) This would have caused the neural network biased to learn more N class than R.